# How to pre-process category info in deeplearning (keras) training input data?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have category information in the training input data, I am wondering what's the best way to normalize it.

The category information is like "city", "gender" and etc.

I'd like to use Keras to handle the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikitlearn has a [preprocessing library](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) with functions to normalize or scale your data.

[This video](https://youtu.be/UkzhouEk6uY) gives an example for how to preprocess data that will be used for training a model with Keras. The preprocessing here is done with the library mentioned above.

As shown in the video, with the use of Scikitlearn's `MinMaxScaler` class, you can specify a range that you want your data to be transformed into, and then fit your data to that range using the `MinMaxScaler.fit_transform()` function.